# НЕ при чем или НИ при чем?

Tags: орфография, не-или-ни

Каждый раз спотыкаюсь: НЕ при чем или НИ при чем? ("Я тут не(ни) при чем")
Спасибо.

Answer (score 16):

В отрицательных местоимениях и наречиях в безударном положении пишется И. Поэтому **ни при чём.**

Answer (score 3):

Да, это так. Причём как при наличии предлога, так и без него: никтО - ни с кЕм, но нЕкто - нЕ с кем

Answer (score 1):

1. Странная логика **в одном из недавних ответов**: «НЕ можно ставить там, где можно писать без НЕ». Откуда это следует?  Такое впечатление, что частное наблюдение возведено в абсолютную истину. Такие формальные решения никогда не гарантируют правильный ответ.
2. Обсуждая эту тему (в одном из своих вопросов в этом году), я сделала для себя такой вывод: усилительные конструкции  могут строиться **в самом предложении**  ***(он не спрашивал ни о чем***), а могут  использоваться в виде **готовой  конструкции**, как  обычно используются фразеологические выражения  (***он здесь ни при чем***).
3. Такая устойчивая конструкция закреплена правилами, в частности это рекомендация **Грамоты.ру**, поэтому лучше использовать эту форму.

[http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=ни+при+чем](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BD%D0%B8+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8+%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC)

4. В то же время **не стоит считать**, что вариант «не при чем» неграмотный и неверный.  Эта тема обсуждалась на форуме  еще один раз,  причем в одном из ответов есть следующая информация:

Правильно: «ни при чем», но интересно то, что форма "не при чем" **использовалась раньше** и продолжает использоваться сейчас (правда, не часто), например:

― Для меня нет сомнения, что ты тут не при чем, ― высказался наконец он яснее (Ф. М. Достоевский. Идиот).

― Слава Богу, ― сказал сын, улыбаясь. ― Бог тут не при чем (Л. Н. Толстой. Война и мир).

[https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/44840/Непричём-как-пра](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/44840/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D1%91%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0)

5. Я доверяю ч**увству языка** у наших классиков.  Не хочется думать, что им было **сложно различить** значения частиц НЕ и НИ, так что они во всем полагались на правила орфографии (которые к тому же в те времена не были так строго регламентированы, как сейчас).
6. **ВЫВОД**

Сочетание  ***ни при чем***  имеет фразеологический характер, как и выражения  *ни рыба ни мясо, ни то ни се, ни дать ни взять, ни жив ни мертв*.

Здесь мы видим **усиление** признака за счет **обобщения**, например: ***ни днем ни ночью*** – это никогда, ***ни проехать ни пройти*** – вообще не пробраться.

*При чем тут он*? *Он здесь **не при чем*** – простое отрицание (сейчас этот вариант не используется),  *он здесь **ни при чем*** – усиленное отрицание (используется  в современной орфографии).

Answer (score 0):

Ориентация на ударное или безударное положение в этом вопросе - чисто формальный, алгоритмический (лишённый смысловой аргументации) подход. Пример: "Ни в понедельник, ни во вторник или другие дни следующей недели я не смогу с вами встретиться". В этом примере (другие примеры тоже существуют) этот подход не работает: человек, произносящий это предложение, вполне может ставить ударение на частицу НИ. Решением может (и должна) быть смысловая или функциональная ориентация. Вопрос: Какую функцию выполняет частица НИ? Ответ: её основная функция - усилительная (при отрицании НЕ). Эту функцию можно реализовать другими словами: "Как в понедельник, так и во вторник или иные дни следующей недели я не смогу с вами встретиться", или "И в понедельник, и во вторник или иные дни ...". 
Тот же принцип распределения ролей между частицами НЕ и НИ в этом предложении присутствует и в других языках. Например, по-английски: "Neither on Monday nor Tuesday or other days of the next week, I will not be able to meet you." Поэтому в случаях, когда человек сомневается, как то или иное писать по-русски, он должен следовать не простым алгоритмам (типа "ударная или безударная позиция"), а самому искать и вырабатывать для себя смысловые аргументы, а также - по возможности - сравнивать те же предложения в других языках. Алгоритмы здесь не годятся хотя бы потому, что человек есть homo sapiens,  он - не робот и не машина.

Следующий вопрос: "НЕ или НИ" в конструкции "не при чём" или "ни при чём"? Возьмите предложение: "В любом варианте я оказываюсь не при деле". Думаю, никому не придёт в голову писать в этом предложении частицу НИ. Потому что смысл не изменится, если то же самое выразить предложением: "В любом варианте я не оказываюсь при деле". Смысл этих предложений одинаков, он - отрицание. Человек здесь отрицает возможность его участия в каком-то деле. Если сказать "Я в этом деле - не при чём", то это - другая, сокращённая форма выразить то же самое отрицание участия в том деле, о котором идёт речь. Но тогда малая трансформация последнего предложения в краткую форму: "Я тут - не при чём" сохраняет тот же смысл отрицания. Мне кажется, что такая аргументация вполне очевидна. Но главное - она строится не на формальном (и довольно субъективном) признаке "ударная или безударная позиция", а на глубоком смысловом анализе этой проблемы.

Comment: Автор вопроса не дождался и не оценит этот обстоятельный труд. Читать трудно, букв много, ответ (вывод) не найти, есть опечатки, нет ссылок на источник знаний. Но мысль интересная.

Comment: Автор этих изменений (устранение опечаток и включение примера по-английски) - не новый, а тот же участник (вошедший сюда под другим именем).

Comment: С текстом бы разобраться, а уж потом с изменениями. Их можно и не принимать, это должен и может решать Автор ответа с помощью «Правки».

Comment: Ориентация на ударное или безударное положение имеет смысл для местоимений. А  большая часть ответа — не об этом.

Answer (score 0):

**Не** можно ставить там, где можно писать без **не**:

```
Я был при делах. => Я был не при делах.
Я шел в самый верх. => Я шел не в самый верх.
Он ушел из-за этого. => Он ушел не из-за этого.
Я был при чем (???). => Я был не при чем (???).
```

Поэтому правильно

```
Я был ни при чем
```