# Непричём - как правильно писать?

Tags: орфография

непричём

Comment: @павел 1, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 8):

Правильно: ни при чем, но интересно то, что форма "не при чем"  использовалась раньше и продолжает использоваться сейчас (правда, не часто), например:

― Для меня нет сомнения, что ты тут не при чем, ― высказался наконец он яснее (Ф. М. Достоевский. Идиот).

― Слава Богу, ― сказал сын, улыбаясь. ― Бог тут не при чем (Л. Н. Толстой. Война и мир).

Скорее всего, дело в том, что использование частицы НИ в данном случае надо объяснить. А как объяснить? Можно сказать, что частица НИ совмещает значения усиления и отрицания, но ведь можно считать, что это просто отрицание и писать частицу НЕ.

Похожий пример: Говорят, что ворон живет ни много ни мало - триста лет. Десять лет - это не много и не мало.

Comment: Я это воспринимаю как сокращение от "ни при том, ни при этом - что ни возьми". Большего внимания требует различение выражений "чего они только не делают - и такое, и этакое вытворяют!" и "что они ни делают, не идут дела".

Comment: Да, Вы как раз очень доходчиво объяснили наличие усилительного значения. Наверное, следует в современной орфографии пользоваться только этой устойчивой формой, и в то же время можно понять, почему классики в приведенных примерах писали "НЕ".

Comment: В  примере  с  вороном  "ни  много  ни  мало" -  фразеологизм.  Очень  много,  значит.

Comment: >В примере с вороном "ни много ни мало" - фразеологизм.   
  
ну это-то да...

>Очень много, значит.  
  
Ой ли? Я согласен, что Vera неправильно трактует пример с вороном, но "очень много" тоже не совсем то. Просто подчеркивает эффект неожиданности.

Answer (score 3):

Правильно: ни при чем

Answer (score 2):

> Скорее всего, дело в том, что использование частицы НИ в данном случае надо объяснить. А как объяснить?

Да Господь с Вами. Что ж тут сложного-то? Ни при чем - это предложный падеж от "ничто" с предлогом "при". Сравните с "ни о чем", "ни на чем" и проч. 
Это и история возникновения и объяснение правописания. ***Он ни при чем = Он ни при чем не состоит***

Вот от форму с **не** (нечто, нечего, нечему... нечем, (?)н**е** о чем) объяснить будет затруднительно - смысл отрицания не просматривается, да и ударение сместилось бы на НЕ.

Что же касается формы "не при чем" в отдельных дореформенных текстах, то тут надо иметь в виду, что единого свода правил тогда не было (его и после революции не было до 1956 г.), различные рекомендации иногда противоречили друг другу, а авторитетность мнения иногда перевешивала или просто подменяла его строгость и обоснованность. Похоже, с последним как раз и связано расхождение в орфографии...

Comment: Действительно, существует простое правило выбора НЕ и НИ для местоимений: НЕ пишется в ударной позиции, а НИ - в безударной. Но это формальное правило, позволяющее нам избежать анализа значений приставок НЕ и НИ: НИ - усиление уже имеющегося отрицания, а НЕ - просто отрицание. Это правило охватывает большую часть написаний, но все-таки не все. Например: При чем тут он? - Он тут не/ни при чем. Здесь нет слова с отрицанием, которое можно усилить, и довольно сложно такое слово подобрать. Пример "Он ни при чем = Он ни при чем не состоит" не очень убедителен.

Comment: Vera, я не понял, если вы мне возражаете, то в чем?  
Какое это все имеет отношение к сказанному мной?  
  
>"Он ни при чем = Он ни при чем не состоит" не очень убедителен.    
    
Ну это кому как. Я не "пример" приводил, а объяснял происхождения конструкции. Вы хотите сказать, что сомневаетесь в том, что это предложный падеж от "ничто, ничего, ничему"? У меня сомнений в том нет ни малейших. Остальное - обсуждаемо, но, наверное, все-таки не на уровне "верю - не верю" (т.е. "пример убедителен" - "не убедителен"). И при чем тут ударная позиция?

Comment: Мне хотелось бы убедить Вас в том, что форма "не при чем" имеет право на существование, наряду с основной "ни при чем". Классическая частица НИ усиливает уже имеющееся отрицание, сравнить: ни о чем не говорить - не о чем говорить. Отрицание может подразумеваться: на небе (нет) ни облачка. В других случаях НИ может совмещать отрицание и усиление, как во фразеологизмах: ни рыба ни мясо. В нашем случае ("он тут не при чем") нет слова с отрицанием, и его сложно подобрать, и это не фразеологизм. Поэтому здесь возможен авторский выбор: обычно пишут НИ, но можно и НЕ.

Answer (score 2):

**НИ ПРИ ЧЁМ.**  Вот что писал **Грот** об этой форме ещё в конце 19-го века:

*"Необходимо также иметь в виду случай, когда местоимение **ничто** разделяется предлогом на свои составные части и когда следовательно отрицание **не** было бы неуместно, напр. в выражениях: **он ушёл ни с чем, он остался ни при чём.** Частица **не** перед косвенными падежами местоимения **что** является **только при неопред. наклонении глагола** и почти всегда носит ударение: **не о чем говорить, не зачем ***[так в оригинале]*** спрашивать***" (Грот Я.К. "Русское правописание").

А ошибки в написании… Что ж, бывают… 
Действительно, в Нацкорпусе имеется пример использования Достоевским написания **"не при чём"**. Один-единственный! И какой из этого примера можно сделать вывод, если ВОСЕМЬ (!) других примеров из Достоевского идут с написанием **"ни при чём"?** См. http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=%28metas%253A%2522author%2522%2520%2526%2520%28%21%25E4%25EE%25F1%25F2%25EE%25E5%25E2%25F1%25EA%25E8%25E9%29%29&mysent=&mysize=1907061&mysentsize=139395&mydocsize=29&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%ED%E8+%EF%F0%E8+%F7%E5%EC

Примерно такая же картина и у Л.Н. Толстого: на один пример с **"не при чём"** -- три примера с **"ни при чём"**:  http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=%28metas%253A%2522author%2522%2520%2526%2520%28%21%25CB.%2520%252F1%2520%21%25CD.%2520%252F1%2520%21%25D2%25EE%25EB%25F1%25F2%25EE%25E9%29%29&mysent=&mysize=1906467&mysentsize=131699&mydocsize=99&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%ED%E8+%EF%F0%E8+%F7%E5%EC

Comment: С точки зрения грамматики, Грот всего лишь указал на совмещение приставкой НИ значения усиления и отрицания, которое широко используется в языке, в частности во фразеологизмах. Это его верное наблюдение. Но с точки зрения той же грамматики, такое совмещение  вовсе не обязательно, и автор имеет право использовать только отрицание. Другое дело что форма "ни при чём" для широких масс является привычной и нет нужды ее переделывать, просто не стоит считать ошибкой написание НЕ.

Comment: А примеры у Грота не очень удачны:  НЕ о чем говорить - НИ о чем НЕ говорить - парный вариант, у нас же пары нет. Формальные установки Грота были хороши в конце 19 века, сейчас же  желательно иметь строгое грамматическое объяснение всем написаниям, иначе нашу орфографию трудно будет оградить от реформ.

Answer (score 1):

"Можно сказать, что частица НИ совмещает значения усиления и отрицания, но ведь можно считать, что это просто отрицание и писать частицу НЕ."
Я считаю, что это самый хороший ответ. Мне лично  больше нравится вариант НЕ при чём. И я так и пишу ))

Answer (score 0):

Я не филолог, а даже наоборот, математик, и мне думается, что имеем отрицание для "при чем".

— При чем тут это?
— Не при чем.

Answer (score -1):

"Ни", как и объяснения его присутствия в этой фразе, представляются мне надуманными, искусственными. "Ни" вместо напрашивающегося "не" выглядит просторечным. Почему "не при делах", "не при детях", но вдруг "ни при чем". Мало ли что "академики" установят. Может быть на них лежит часть вины за упадок русского языка с того времени, как он стал "регулироваться" административно.

Comment: *с того времени, как он стал "регулироваться" административно*  - не назовете дату, когда это произошло? А то мы и не знали, что уже так. И еще хорошо бы информацию о тех доводах, которые Вы считаете "надуманными". Может, Вы не те доводы читаете?

Comment: Кстати, у меня **не** здесь совсем и не "напрашивается". А аналогия с "не при делах" - ошибочна, ибо "ни при чем" есть падежная форма от "ничто". Про "не при делах"  такого сказать невозможно. Нет такого местоимения "нидела". )))

Answer (score -1):

Считаю, что правильно писать "НЕ при чём".
Писать  здесь НИ  демонстрирует глухоту к русскому языку. 
Если подряд ставить две гласные "и" - "нИ прИ" - они сталкиваются и диссонируют.
Проверку можно было бы устроить, послушав народную речь в тех местах, где безударные "И" и "Е" четко произносят. Мне кажется, это могут быть Владимирская или Вологодская области, но хорошо, если выскажется специалист в диалектах.

Comment: Важно не то, как вы считаете, а как надо писать. А писать надо ***ни при чем***. Согласно словарям и справочникам.